# Как НЕ попадать в дизассемблированный код при отладке? Clion

Tags: c++, c, отладка, clion

Допустим я дебажу код, а именно в Clion, жму f8 т.е.пройти не заходя внутрь(step out), но у меня все равно попадает в другие разделы допустим в boost а там вообще прыгает в disassembly. Как этого избегать?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Перепрыгивать такие функции. Вообще, никогда не заходите в функции исходного кода от которых у вас нет, и вас не будет кидать в дизассемблер.

Comment: @ori по-другому никак? мб флаг какой-нибудь есть мол "не заходить в disassembly", как бы глупо не звучало:)

Comment: f8 это step over и он не заходит внутрь, разве что там произошел какой-то кирдык. Но и при этом он не должен попадать в ассемблер. А если попадает, то значит для этого кода по какой-то причине отсутствуют отладочные символы.